# How to cover the test class for external objects Query in test class

Tags: unit-test, lightning-connect

Can anyone suggest me how to cover the SOQL code line in test class.
Due to Query failing i am not able to increase the code coverage to 75% minimum for class.
Suggest me how can i achieve this .
Is there any other way to increase the code coverage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mocking the external object API calls is not properly supported by SFDC yet. However, there is a pretty neat workaround by Graham Barnard. It does require some redesign of your External Object queries and it will not give you 100% test coverage (because of the `isRunnningTest()` statement). But it will allow you to functionally test the code that calls the external objects

http://grahambarnard.com/development/2016/02/08/mocking-external-objects/

Comment: I have tried and it is working.I wanted to make sure that ,will it be effected system if i use this approach  means allows that calls the external objects  functionally test the code that calls the external objects

Comment: It is passing the SOQL but the data is not coming ,when i checked the debug logs  records are not showing in list for soql. Let me know if there is any idea about it.

Comment: The Mock service will not really do a request to the external object. That is impossible in test classes. You will need to add 'fake' results in your test code, e.g. like in the example: ExternalRequestModel.mockedRequests.add(mockedRequest);